# When using rules to set an entity reference, do I use node or node:nid?

Tags: 7, rules, entities

I am using rules to create nodes.  Whenever a specific field on my target node-type is changed, a new new will be created and linked to the target node via entity reference field.  I would like to know, when setting an entity reference field using rules, should I use the data selector 'node' or the data selector 'node:nid'?

Comment: Have you tried either option?

Comment: The answer: just the node.  Anyone want to explain for the win?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting an entity reference with rules, there is no need to specify the nid field. setting the value to the node itself will work.